# Logs of the invoked aws lambda in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Need to find logs of the invoked lambda from another lambda. How can I do that using Java? I have the request id of the first lambda.

I have invoked lambda 1 which publishes a message to SNS topic and this triggers lambda 2 to run. I need to find out the logs of lambda 2. I have the request id of invocation of lambda 1, if this could be of any help.

Comment: Lambda reports logs to Cloudwatch. Read from Cloudwatch using SDK and passing the required params .

Answer (score 0):

When you login to AWS console, navigate to the Lambda whose logs you want to see, navigate to monitoring tab and click on 'View Cloudwatch logs' and there you can see the log streams